# How to upload a file to a specific folder using php?

Tags: php

My code is as follows..Here when I upload a file named Koala.jpg,then the warning is shown--Warning: copy(Koala.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\Forum\upload.php on line 4
Could not copy file!..Please solve the problem urgently..

```
Select a file to upload: <br />
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
            </form>

***upload.php***

<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" )
{
   copy( $_FILES['file']['name'], "/uploads" ) or 
           die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else
{
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Uploading Complete</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Uploaded File Info:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
<li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?> bytes
<li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'];  ?>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) rather than [copy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php).... uploaded files go to a temp directory and move_uploaded_file() is aware of this; but you also need to specify the folder as a filesystem path, not a web path; and the destination should include a filename as well as a path

Comment: You have not spacified the path.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
if( $_FILES['file']['name'] != "" ) {
    $path=$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $pathto="/uploads/".$path;
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$pathto) or die( "Could not copy file!");
}
else {
    die("No file specified!");
}
?>
```

**Source** :

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlupload.php

Answer (score 1):

Replace copy function by following

```
$destFile = "/root/mysite/upload_files/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destFile );
```

Note the location is a filesystem destination *not* a URL. Also the filesystem path is relative to the highest root rather than the website home URL.

Comment: You should not use `copy` for that purpose because the file might be in a temporary folder. Prefer `move_uploaded_file` instead.

Comment: Yes, i knew it, but answer was related to question, anyway i edited my answer.

Comment: The destination of the file will simply be either the domain root or the PHP current wording directory, neither of which are probably good places to dump the file, this also does not illustrate to the OP that `$destFile` should be a filesystem path rather than a file name or browser URL .